# Selecting element and replacing text inside each()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list which looks like the following:

```
<ul id="offers">

<li class="unique-id-here">
<span class="country">US</span>
<span class="clicks">192</span>
<span class="ctr">9%</span>
</li>

</ul>
```

And i am trying to update the .clicks with new values every 5 seconds.

So my though was, select each li -> get the unique-id-here -> save the id to a variable -> to a $.get request to request the clicks for that given id -> replace the current clicks with the new ones.

Problem is that i cannot seem to select the .clicks properly... this is what my jQuery code looks like:

```
var refreshId = setInterval(function() {

$("#offers li").each(function(){

    var a = $(this).attr('class');      
    if(a) {

            $.get("ajax.php", { opt: "stats", oid: a }, function(r) {
                var j = eval('(' + r + ')');

                $(this).find('.clicks').text('<strong>'+j.message.clicks+'%</strong>');

            });
    }
});
}, 5000);
```

Any ideas on how i can replace the .clicks value of each li field properly?

Help is much appreciated :)

Comment: When you say that the "problem is that i cannot seem to select the .clicks properly." - what do you mean by properly?

Comment: sorry, i mean how i can do it so that it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var refreshId = setInterval(function() {

$("#offers li").each(function(){
    var $li = $(this), 
        a = $li.attr('class');      
    if(a) {
            $.get("ajax.php", { opt: "stats", oid: a }, function(r) {
                var j = eval('(' + r + ')');
                $li.find('.clicks').html('<strong>'+j.message.clicks+'%</strong>');
            });
    }
});
}, 5000);
```

You are using `$(this)` inside the `$.get`, which would refer to another object. Also, why are you using `eval`? Why not return a JSON object to the request?

In addition, you are using `text()`, however the string you pass to the parameter contains HTML (`<strong>`). Thus, I switched `text()` with `html()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
var refreshId = setInterval(function() {

    $("#offers li").each(function(){
        var clicks = $(this).find('.clicks');
        var a = $(this).attr('class');      
        if(a) {

                $.get("ajax.php", { opt: "stats", oid: a }, function(r) {
                    var j = eval('(' + r + ')');

                    clicks.text('<strong>'+j.message.clicks+'%</strong>');

                });
        }
    });
    }, 5000);
```

i think that your problem is that $(this) inside the success function of tha AJAX call has not the scope you think. another thing you could do is:

```
var refreshId = setInterval(function() {

    $("#offers li").each(function(){
        var $that = $(this);
        var a = $(this).attr('class');      
        if(a) {

                $.get("ajax.php", { opt: "stats", oid: a }, function(r) {
                    var j = eval('(' + r + ')');

                    $that.find('.clicks').text('<strong>'+j.message.clicks+'%</strong>');

                });
        }
    });
    }, 5000);
```